# Wordpress Contact form 7: Google Analytics Tracking

Tags: wordpress

I've got contact form 7 installed. I've followed the documentation to add tracking code to the : additional settings field in wordpress (http://contactform7.com/2009/11/24/tracking-form-submissions-with-google-analytics/) but then recieved pageTracker object errors.

Anyone else experienced this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the previous comment above i ended up solving this issue by adding a psuedo page:

the page url becomes:

/?completed=1 ;

Answer (score 0):

Chris,

Not sure if you've resolved this but I am having the same problem...

I've made some changes and am waiting patiently for analytics to track some events but I believe I have found the problem...

The code that the Contact Form is suggesting to use is

```
pageTracker._trackPageview('/mysite/thank-you.html');
```

I have since done some research to discover that this code is the traditional code that I am not using to track analytics data... I have implemented the Async tracking code which requires this implementation:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', "/mysite/thank-you.html"]);
```

More information can be found at Google - http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageview

You should check what google analytics code you are using within your page - if you see _gaq then it is async

Comment: I've actually resolved this by having it visit a psuedo page -> /?completed=1 ; then adding this url as a goal in google analytics. a hack but works for my situation. P.s. thanks for your insight!